# Rspec - is invalid without a title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Hello i have a very simple Rspec test.

It was working until i used Factory Girl. I have tried so many ways to get it to pass.

I have been trying to get it pass for like 90 minutes its such a simple test.

Anyone know?

Here is error

```
 1) Size is invalid without a title
     Failure/Error: let(:size02) { FactoryGirl.create :size02 }
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Title can't be blank
```

This is the test

```
    require 'rails_helper'
    RSpec.describe Size, type: :model do

    let(:size01) { FactoryGirl.create :size01 }
    let(:size02) { FactoryGirl.create :size02 }
    let(:size03) { FactoryGirl.create :size03 }

    it "should have a matching title" do
        expect(size01.title).to eq("XXLarge")
    end

    it "is invalid without a title" do
      expect(size02).to be_invalid
    end

end
```

Factory Girl

```
FactoryGirl.define do

    factory :size01, :class => Size do
        title "XXLarge"
    end

    factory :size02, :class => Size do
        title ""
    end

    factory :size03, :class => Size do
        title "XXLarge"
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factory Girl cannot create the instance `size02`, because it has no title and is therefore invalid. Try `build` instead of `create`, if you don't need persistence in your test:

```
let(:size02) { FactoryGirl.build :size02 }
```

Comment: that worked thank you. I will look up build. See what it does.

Comment: Do that, it is an important difference. Build doen't save to the database and is therefore much faster. If the database isn't important for your test case you should go with build.

Comment: also check out build_stubbed